# Add Custom MassAction for Status

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom

How to Add Custom MassAction In Controller For Status?

My Status Having

1. Accepted
2. Not Process
3. Rejected
4. Re-Offer

So how can I Get These Values in `change status` in MassAction? I Put Default MassAction But Getting "Enable" And "Disable" Value for the Status.

`MassAction`

```
public function massStatusAction()
{

    $pricenegotiateIds = (array)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $pricenegotiateModel  = Mage::getModel('pricenegotiate/pricenegotiate')->load($pricenegotiateIds);
        print_r($pricenegotiateIds);exit;
    $status     = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('status'); //get Status
    if($status==2)
    {
        $couponcode=(rand(10,100));
        echo $couponcode."<br>";
    }
    print_r($status);die;
    //your logic
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code which you have in your module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `Grid.php`

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $statuses = array(
        0=>'Accepted',
        1=>'Not Process',
        2=>'Rejected',
        3=>'Re-Offer'
    );

    array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
         'label'=> $this->__('Change status'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
         'additional' => array(
                'visibility' => array(
                     'name' => 'status',
                     'type' => 'select',
                     'class' => 'required-entry',
                     'label' => $this->__('Status'),
                     'values' => $statuses
                 )
         )
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

in your controller

```
public function massStatusAction()
{
    $status     = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('status'); //get Status

    //your logic
}
```

For reference check below core files

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

and

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php

Comment: Excellent Bro... +1 For your Answer.

Comment: But in the database status value can not change after submit button clicked. so can you pls how to fix that ?

Comment: add your `massStatusAction()` @H_Parekh

Comment: I Put `massStatusAction()` in the question, so pls see the question.

Comment: you have not set the status for your `pricenegotiateModel` then how it will change the status @H_Parekh